# VSCode Breadcrumbs for C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, breadcrumbs

I've wanted to ask a few questions here before I post a bug report. (Also the lines between VSCode and Extension are blurred for me as I never know which to report the problem to)

Question #1: Is there a way for me to force breadcrumbs to update? Sometimes on a new file it is unable to find the C++ symbols contained in that file. Also if you were to change the location of the code by say tabbing it to the bottom the of page, VSCode breadcrumbs would send you to the old location. GIFS below:

Unable to find some C++ symbols:
[image]

Sending to old location: (I saved the document after moving the location which didn't help breadcrumbs)
[image]

Question #2: Do you have to enable symbol highlighting for breadcrumbs? What I am referring to is when I focus over a class it doesn't highlight the whole class just where it was declared.

Whats happening:
[image]

What I was expecting to happen:
[image]

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are problems with the c++ tool's extensions implementation of the breadcrumbs feature. Please try filing issues against that extension.

Looks like [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2230) already tracks some of what you describe